# Android: How to get bitmap's scaled width in onDraw()

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

Simple question where the simple answer isn't working. I have a bitmap and I want to get its dimensions as scaled to the display by the system for different DPI screens within the onDraw() method. bitmap.width() returns its unscaled width successfully. However, bitmap.getScaledWidth() returns zero. I have tried getScaledWidth(canvas) and getScaledWidth(canvas.getDensity()), but both return 0. Indeed, canvas.getDensity() returns zero so I can't even calculate it manually.

What am I doing wrong?

Bit more detail. I'm using a custom view. The bitmap is declared in the class and loaded in the constructor.

Edit:

I've found that using:

```
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

bitmap.getScaledHeight(metrics) returns the same value as bitmap.getHeight().

It would appear that bitmap.getWidth() returns the dimension of the resident bitmap after it has been scaled, meaning there's no apparent way to get the bitmap's original width.

Comment: how did you scale the bitmap?

Comment: Are you using ``new Canvas()`` for getting density or the one you receive for ``onDraw(Canvas)``?

Comment: By scaling I mean the Android system scaling the bitmap to the display DPI automatically. I'm using the canvas from onDraw(Canvas canvas). I pass that canvas to the getSacledWidth(canvas) method and it's returning zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Canvas class has a lots of overloads for the drawBitmap() function. One of them allows you to scale/cut a Bitmap through a pretty comfortable interface.

[`public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint`)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

Where

- **Bitmap bitmap** - is your bitmap you want to draw
- **Rect src** - the source rect from your bitmap. If its not null, it will
  cut out a piece from your bitmap (in the size and position of src)
- **RectF dst** - This Rect will represent the Rectangle, your Bitmap will
  fit in.
- **Paint paint** - optional paint

And now an example! Lets say, you want to shrink your Bitmaps **width** to ***1/2*** and increase its **height** to ***2*** times of the original:

```
float startX = 0; //the left
float startY = 0; //and top corner (place it wherever you want)
float endX = startX + bitmap.getWidth() * 0.5f; //right
float endY = startY + bitmap.getHeight() * 2.0f; //and bottom corner

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new RectF(startX, startY, endX, endY), null);
```

**UPDATE**

I don't really understand, what you are trying to acomplish, after reading your comment, but here is some extra info to get started:

Get the original size of a Bitmap without loading it into the memory:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true; // bitmap wont be loaded into the memory

//won't load the Bitmap, but the options will contain the required information.
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
/*or*/ BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

int originalWidth = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
int originalHeight = bitmapOptions.outHeight;
```

Now if you have another your actual (scaled) `Bitmap`, or an `ImageView`, what you want  to compare to the original, then you can use this (to get the width and height use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`):

```
/*Get these values*/
int originalWidth, originalHeight, scaledWidth, scaledHeight; 

float scaleWidthRatio = (float)scaledWidth / originalWidth;
float scaleHeightRatio = (float)scaledHeight / originalHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not wanting to scale a bitmap on drawing, but instead I want to know how it has been scaled by the system to match the screen DPI. eg. If I have a graphic created for a 160 DPI screen and it's displayed on a 120 DPI screen, I need to get how much it has been shrunk by (which should return 0.75 or somesuch) so that I can scale other factors by that same amount.

Comment: Yeah, I had just found that earlier. ;) Effectively bitmaps are loaded and scaled by default, but using bitmapfactory.options, it's possible to control how they are loaded, including loading it unscaled and scaling manually which is what others were suggesting. What I was after isn't explicitly available in Android so we use these workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You scale the bitmap yourself. :-)

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if(drawable==null)
            Log.d("onDraw()","getDrawable returns null");

        Bitmap  fullSizeBitmap,scaledBitmap = null,roundBitmap = null;

        fullSizeBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;

        //get width & height of ImageView
        int scaledWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int scaledHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        //bitmap, which will receive the reference to a bitmap scaled to the bounds of the ImageView.
        if(fullSizeBitmap!=null)
        scaledBitmap= getScaledBitmap(fullSizeBitmap,scaledWidth,scaledHeight);

        //Now, draw the bitmap on the canvas
        if(roundBitmap!=null)
           canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0 , null);
}
```